# SQL Alchemy tries to log in through Windows user instead of the one specified in the URL

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create_engine() with a schema that I know for sure works with SQLite and MySQL.

I have created a docker image of PostgreSQL with the following docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    ports:
      - "5325:5432"
    expose:
      - 5325
```

And I am trying to connect using the following URL: `"postgresql:///test:test@localhost:5325/test"`

When I do that, I get an error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "taras"`,

where "taras" is my OS username.

**Why is SQL Alchemy trying to log in to a user which I have never specified anywhere in my code?**

Comment: Should't this: `postgresql:///...` be `postgresql://...` or for more clarity: `postgresql+psycopg2://...`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no, triple slash is needed for sql alchemy I believe. In any case, doing two slashed throws a URL parsing error. Using ```postgresql+psycopg2``` didn't change anything, still the same error.

Comment: Someone forgot to tell SQLAlchemy that: [psycopg2 connection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2). And it works for me: `from sqlalchemy import create_engine engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://aklaver:@localhost:5432/test') engine Engine(postgresql+psycopg2://aklaver:***@localhost:5432/test)`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver to be clear, I am not having issues connecting to postgresql in general. I can easily connect to an instance running on AWS. The issue comes from connecting to the docker image.

Comment: Then you are going to need to show more of what you are doing in the code that makes the connection. FYI, `libpq`(the library `psycopg2` uses) looks to these [env](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) variables for connection information.

Comment: There really isn't much to it. It just fails on the first engine.execute(CreateSchema(name))  that I have. Stack trace fails on the connection side, nothing to do with the schema.

Comment: Yet it is failing, so there is something to it. Please add to the question the code segment that leads up to:`first engine.execute(CreateSchema(name))`. The error you are getting is what you get if the connection is not getting a user name. In that case it will substitute in a default of the OS user name. So something is failing to pick up the user name you are supplying.

Comment: It should be `postgresql://test:test@localhost:5325/test`: using three slashes is telling sqla that the database name is `test:test@localhost:5325/test` and postgres will fall back to using your user name for the login.

Comment: @TarasKuzyk, and what's your platform?

Comment: @NadeemTaj Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @snakecharmerb and @Adrian Klaver explained in their comments above, I had to use two slashes, as otherwise SQL Alchemy interprets the name of the database as `test:test@localhost:5325/test`

With two slashes the issue was gone on MySQL because I had a different user name on the database, and a different error was preventing me from creating a PostgreSQL DB.

The problem was with me parsing a URL before creating the engine, as @Adrian Klaver has pointed out.

```
def _create_schema_from_url(self, url):
        schema_name = self._get_schema_name_from_url(url)
        url_with_no_schema = url.replace(f"/{schema_name}", "") # <-- logical error
        self.engine = self._get_engine(url_with_no_schema)
        try:
            self._create_schema(schema_name)
        except ProgrammingError:
            self._recreate_schema(schema_name)
```

with url `postgres://test:test@localhost:5325/test` I ended up putting `postgres:/:test@localhost:5325` into create_engine, which caused it to fail.

Correcting the logical error line to
`url_with_no_schema = url[:-len(schema_name)]`
fixed the problem for me.

**TLDR:** naive URL parsing error